# importing python packages for aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to test my aws lambda function but when i run it the function fails with the error `Unable to import module 'property_endpoint': cannot import name 'MProperty'`

My folder structure is

```
Property/
    custom_exceptions/
        __init__.py
        custom_exceptions.py
    property_package/
        __init__.py
        mproperty.py
        property_manager.py
    pymysql/
    PyMySQL-0.7.11.dist-info/
    property_endpoint.py
```

and when i create my deployment package i just zip the contents of Property/

The lambda handler is in `property_endpoint.py`.

At the top of property_endpoint.py I try to import my packages like this

```
import logging
from typing import Optional
from custom_exceptions.custom_exceptions import *
from property_package.mproperty import MProperty
from property_package.property_manager import PropertyManager
```

The file the error is about (MProperty) looks like this

```
import json
from property_package.property_manager import PropertyManager

class MProperty:
....
```

It doesn't complain about the 3 above it which i seem to be importing in the same way

I'm new to python so not sure if I'm going about this in completely the wrong way. I've found similar posts here but nothing has seemed to solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to move your souce code to the root of zip file? Not under `Property`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried it but get the same error. I might just have to go back to basics and create a really simple example and try that.

Comment: If anyone else comes across this, I got it working in the end.  There were a few problems but I think the main thing was that i was trying to type hint the class MProperty in the function arguments. I changed it to 'MProperty' and it seems to work.